# How to display a website (not hosted) within another website that IS hosted?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popupwindow, portfolio

I am creating a portfolio website that WILL HAVE A DOMAIN AND WILL BE HOSTED. For the purposes of the below questions, my portfolio website will be "website #1" and the project website will be "website #2."

I am creating website #1 (has domain/is hosted). I want to showcase website #2 (no domain/not hosted) within website #1 without having to purchase a domain/host for it. Website #2 was a school project so I do not want to spend money on a domain or hosting services.

Ideally, there would be a button the user can click on website #1, another browser window pops up within website #1, and loads the local files of website #2. The background of website #1 is still visible, but the popup browser window now has focus (see image).

If this is possible, do you know if website #2 would be responsive to the popup window? It would be great if the user could resize the popup window to see the responsiveness of it.

Hopefully, I have explained everything well enough the second time around to get some help. Thank you in advance! :)

[image: Popup window]

Comment: You can basically load the website #2 in website #1 itself, and yes you can code it to be responsive.

Comment: Just reference the hierarchy folder of the website you wish to showcase. So you have your file structure for your hosted site... Top level folder with index page, then you have a folder called webProjects. Then place the folder structure of your showcased site within that folder and when you want to reference it, reference that folder>index.html.

Comment: In ReactNative there is something called WebView, guess there should also be something similar in ReactJS and it might help

Answer (score 0):

You can place projects websites in /projects/ directory and then refer to them as for example: https://yourportfolio.com/projects/schoolproject.

To display it in your portfolio website you can use **iframe** tag and it can be responsive if you code it correctly.